When did the distinction between "pure" and "applied" mathematics become common?
Some ages ago, there was no difference between chemistry, physics, mathematics, and perhaps even philosophy. These were not further distinguished and largely practiced by the same people.
Obviously, this is no longer the case. The different disciplines have differentiated and themselves have become split into subdisciplines.
I am interested at what point the distinction between pure and applied mathematics first appeared within the mathematical community (if a mathematical community even existed at that point). That includes, in particular, when terminology "pure" and "applied" first appeared.
(edit) On top of that, it is of interest whether this discourse occurred in non-Western traditions in a similar manner. Mathematicians at the Indian Kerala school or the Chinese Imperial Court may have had different point of views.

GPT4 gives a convincing answer: the term appeared in the late 19th century when specialization and the math community began to be large enough. The last universal mathematicians were probably Hilbert and Poincaré, who both worked somewhat in applied maths. Hilbert in continuum physics, eg with the Riemann-Hilbert shock problem, Poincaré in celestial mechanics. It is also the time when rigor demands increased, with the push to formalize maths - Frege, Dedekind, Peano, Hilbert,... So there was a growing gap between math and physics, where applied maths sprang. WW1 then promoted this trend.

Let me mention that such a distinction appears in F. Klein's Development of Mathematics in the 19th Century in the context of Gauß, thus it should be at least earlier than when F. Klein wrote this.

I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for HSMSE.

@pm ChatGPT is designed to be convincing. Go and find some primary sources to back up its claims and then tell people. Anything ChatGPT generates is hardly admissible evidence in court... :-)

Hi @DavidRoberts, Thank you, i will try that. Under space constraint i did not precise that the only thing i picked from GPT4 was « the term appeared in the late 19th century ». The rest is the unsafe product of my own brain - sorry. ZM references Klein, that would be from the late 19th century. Carlo also gives facts compatible with the late 19th century. As a side note i find it sane exercise to use GPTn every now and then, paying attention to biases, style, accuracy. I also keep in mind analyses like https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.06981 . Finally i happen to have rarely been convinced by GPTn.

The correct spelling is ‘Kerala’. The word ‘Karela’ means a bitter gourd (vegetable) in a certain language in India.

The distinction between pure and applied mathematics goes back to the ancient Greeks, where it was referred to as the study of the world of ideas (pure) versus the world of the senses (applied).
Plutarch makes the distinction in his Life of Marcellus, citing Plato:

For the art of mechanics, now so celebrated and admired, was first
originated by Eudoxus and Archytas, who embellished geometry with its
subtleties, and gave to problems incapable of proof by word and
diagram, a support derived from mechanical illustrations that were
patent to the senses. For instance, in solving the problem of finding
two mean proportional lines, a necessary requisite for many
geometrical figures, both mathematicians had recourse to mechanical
arrangements, adapting to their purposes certain intermediate portions
of curved lines and sections.
But Plato was incensed at this, and
inveighed against them as corrupters and destroyers of the pure
excellence of geometry, which thus turned her back upon the
incorporeal things of abstract thought and descended to the things of
sense, making use, moreover, of objects which required much mean and
manual labour. For this reason mechanics was made entirely distinct
from geometry, and being for a long time ignored by philosophers, came
to be regarded as one of the military arts.

More Greek references are in the Wikipedia entry.
The terms "pure" versus "applied" came in use in the 19th century, with journals such as Journal fur die reine und angewandte Mathematik (founded 1826), and Journal de mathematiques pures et appliquee (founded 1836).

I was reading just before your edit on Crelle's journal. I am not sure to find in the Plutarch quote a distinction between pure and applied maths as we understand them nowadays.

@plm: independently on what Plutarch says, the distinction is quite clear. Euclid and Apollonius were pure mathematicians, while Ptolemy applied. Archimedes did both. You never see such things as trigonometry, for example in the work on pure mathematics.

@plm There is even no absolute consensus today. For example, in France, PDE is usually classified as applied, including more theoretic parts, while it does not seem to be so in the US, say.

Hi @AlexandreEremenko, thank you, interesting slide to "mathematicians". I think it makes much of a difference to talk about persons as opposed to (bodies of) results. A person has a routine, his collected works, a personality. Much of it is not easily reflected by the subject he thinks about. Ptolemy had results on classical geometry -or astronomy- that hardly anyone would call applied maths. I don't dwell. Thank you for sharing your point of view. I think preferences for definitions may vary here.

@Z.M Thank you, i agree there is no consensus. Like on most intuitive, vague terms. It depends very much on each person's own preferences, especially in mathematics where esthetics is crucial. And yes, a nation's culture and maths community has a major role. Regarding PDE i am not sure. In Bordeaux the Département d'analyse has or had people working on PDE who really didnt do applied maths - Haak, Ouhabaz,... Some famous french mathematicians working on PDE are rather pure: PL Lions, C Villani, C Mouhot,... I'll trust you about the usual classification, im no specialist.

The question is whether there is continuity from the Ancient Greek conceptualization of mathematics (whatever they conceived as math) to the modern way of doing it. On top of that, Ancient Greece is now seen as the origin of "Western" culture. What about mathematics in, say, China, India, or Persia?

Z. M. Certainly one should classify the bodies of research rather than persons. At all times there were persons who did both pure and applied mathematics (from Newton to von Neumann, especially in 19 century, and there are such mathematicians today).

J. reine angew. Math. and J. math. pures appl. were predated by Magazin für reine und angewandte Mathematik and Archiv der reinen und angewandten Mathematik (Leipzig 1786–1800), resp. Annales de mathématiques pures et appliquées (Nîmes 1810–1832).

@FrancoisZiegler It's remarkable that we're still using the same terms for the fundamental division of the subject almost 250 years later.

The ancient Greeks were quite strict in their separation of pure mathematics (mathematics) and applied mathematics (logistics). Euclid in his elements covered the basics of pure mathematics: line segments were not measured (there are no units, neither for lengths, nor for areas or angles) but compared to each other, and proportions were described in terms of integers; the unit was not divisible (there is not a single fraction in Euclid). Everything related to measures of lengths (which is pretty much anything you would find in Heron) was called logistics; this includes even the Arithmetica of Diophantus since he did not regard the unit as not divisible: there are fractions everywhere in his books.
The distinction between mathematics and logistics is not quite the same as the modern one between pure and applied mathematics, and this is reflected in the generalization of the notion of "number" that took place long after Euclid, when mathematicians freely used the decimal system and fractions, and later quadratic and higher irrationals.

On the other hand, Greek pure mathematics was the result of an abstraction process always starting from concrete problems  and aimed to concrete applications. For instance, the interest on conics comes from the geometry of projectors, and acustics of theaters. According to Lucio Russo, Euclid's Elements is an abstract model for technical drawing.
